# Writing binary from string to file

Tags: java, string, algorithm, binary

I have a string in my code that has a bunch of 0s and 1s. Now I want to make a file from this string that the bits inside, are characters of this string. How can I do it?

Comment: Look at operators such as AND, OR, SHR, and SHL.  Other than that, what are you asking?  If you are asking for a basic tutorial, this is not the appropriate venue,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function will decode the binary string to a byte array:

```
static byte[] decodeBinary(String s) {
    if (s.length() % 8 != 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "Binary data length must be multiple of 8");
    byte[] data = new byte[s.length() / 8];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c == '1') {
            data[i >> 3] |= 0x80 >> (i & 0x7);
        } else if (c != '0') {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid char in binary string");
        }
    }
    return data;
}
```

Then you can write the byte array to a file with [`Files.write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#write-java.nio.file.Path-byte:A-java.nio.file.OpenOption...-) (or an `OutputStream`):

```
String s = "0100100001100101011011000110110001101111"; // ASCII "Hello"
byte[] data = decodeBinary(s);
java.nio.file.Files.write(new File("file.txt").toPath(), data);
```

Comment: @Masious It rejects strings containing a number of bits that is not divisible by 8, because you can't represent those in files, because files are a whole number of bytes long, and each byte is 8 bits.

Comment: But I need to put that in my file anyway. Should I add some "0" at the beginning of the string?

Comment: @Masious You certainly can, but then the conversion is lossy because it doesn't quite preserve the original string.